# How to extract single items from useQuery when accessing cache in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

New to React-query, and I can't find any example of usage other than with rickandmorty api. The problem I'm having is that rickandmorty has episode/character id contained in the endpoint address, so you can pass that id, get data from the query cache and display it in another page. My api [endpoint](https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6231abada703bb67492d2b8f) doesn't have an id contained. It looks like this: https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6231abada703bb67492d2b8f.

```
    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(
        'directories',
        fetchDirectories,
    );
```

After fetching, data is displayed in a list view. Clicking on each list item should take you to the details page for each item. I don't understand how to reference a particular item when calling useQuery in the details page. How to find a specific item in that cache?

Click navigates you to the url that has a business id as part of the url. How to access that business in the details page?

```
onClick={() => navigate(`business/${object.id}`)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that your backend is missing a detailed view. So you would have to use the list query on your details page, I would advise against this in a real world scenario. On your detailed view component you can consume the hook using the same id and it should get it from the cache (it will trigger a refetch though unless you configure the `staleTime` to something different than 0)

assuming you did:

```js
// ListComponent.jsx
    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(
        'directories',
        fetchDirectories,
        {staleTime: 5000}
    );
```

You should be able to do

```js
    // DetailedView.jsx
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery(
        'directories',
        fetchDirectories,
        staleTime: 5000
    );

   const myItem = data.find(item => item.id === id);
```

or you can get it straight from the cache like you mentioned, but If the cache is empty and react-query doesn't know the fetching function you will get nothing back from the cache

```
 const data = queryClient.getQueryData('directories')
```

In an idea case what you want to do is fetch the list view, and maybe use [setQueryData](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetquerydata) to get data to the individual queries like `useQuery('directory', 1)` so they have data before hitting the **detailed endpoint** which doesn't exist for your backend as far as I know. You can accomplish what you want by using `setQueryData` and `getQueryData` as a work around for your lack of detailed endpoint, but more often than not you will want to work with `useQuery` and not handle the cache like this.

Comment: Gerardo, thank you. I was thinking to myself that something's wrong with the API design. I didn't want to fetch the data on the Details page, and the other solution that I had was storing an id in state and passing it to the Details and then querying cache. I went with the useParams route.

Comment: Do you maybe have a suggestion on how to edit the title of this post so that people can find it more easily? Someone is bound to find themselves in the same situation as I.

Comment: maybe something along the lines of "how to extract single items from a useQuery that fetches a list view" ?